# Regexp matching contents between two commas after a string

Tags: regex

I am struggling with regex in Notepad++ to match the content between the first two commas after "patching_rect" : [" in this single line of text:

> "patching_rect" : [ 218.5, 165.0, 150.0, 20.0 ],

In this case the desired match is " 165.0".

I managed to match the first of the 4 coordinates with:

```
(?<="patching_rect" : \[ ).*?(?=,)
```

But I want to match the second one. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean `patching_rect[1]` ?

Comment: I need to replace the "165.0" by "0.0." But that 165.0 can also be another number.

Comment: Is "patching_rect" guaranteed to appear at the start of the line?

Comment: Are you trying to replace multiple lines with this regex?

Comment: @Tom Yes it is.

Comment: @Someone It is just one line of text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother with lookbehinds. Here's a solution. Replace this:

```
("patching_rect"\s*:\s*\[[^,]+,\s*)[^,]+
```

With this:

```
${1}0.0
```

What this does is quite simple:

- `"patching_rect"\s*:\s*\[` matches everything up to and including the `[`
- `[^,]+,\s*` matches the first value and the comma, and the following whitespace
- `[^,]+` matches the second value

The first part is captured in `$1`, and reused in the replacement string.

Comment: You could also use `\K` to omit everything in front of the desired match.

Comment: @SebastianProske yes, good point. OP: replace `"patching_rect"\s*:\s*\[[^,]+,\s*\K[^,]+` with `0.0`

Comment: Perfect! Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got it: The trick is to replace the whole start of the line with the same thing and then replace the number after it:

This goes in Find: `("patching_rect" ?: ?\[[^,]+,) ?([^,]+)`
This goes in Replace: `$1 0.0`

The question marks are there so that spaces are optional, just in case.